# efficient Communication in two Apps

Tags: java, serialization, applications

I have two applications, first is like starting point and the main app is second one.
Whenever i have to do something, i have to login to the App1, provide some details to it, then App1 builds a Session(sort of a custom session, embeds lots of serialized data) and then re-direct the session to App2. Once I am done with App2, it finally re-directs to App1 and work flow closes.
Both the apps share some of the Objects which they work on.

The problem I am facing is due to this serialized data, the Session Object becomes too heavy and it takes time transitioning from App1 to App2. also there is an overhead of Serialization/De-serialization.
Any ideas on how can I improve it?

Comment: You might be able to patch in compression, or a more efficient serialization. Also, I think it is unlikely that App2 immediately accesses the serialized data in its entirety, so both apps could authenticate into the same persistence layer/server and do almost entirely without the exchanged session. The total access time would be identical (assuming the deserialization is negligible), but more spread out and with less lag.

Comment: If serialization really is the problem, you can improve it by using a binary format instead of a text format.  I doubt serialization is really the problem, though it's hard to tell what's really going on here with so little information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does the second application need all the "session" information to start working?

If not, couldn't you "stream" session informations while the second application started running?

As an example, the first one could act as a "server" for the second one by answering queries about needed data.

Of course, if the second application need most/all of the informations, especially upfront, there's no shortcut. Excepted by using some kind or shared memory/same VM scheme. Are both applications written in the same language (I see your question is tagged "Java")? Do you have control over their source code?

Comment: Yep, second application uses this information to start working. Both application are java based and I have control of source code for both.                I am thinking to keep the session object light and handle it through shared memory(DB) as both applications share same Db

Comment: OK. Is there a reason why both applications cannot run in the same JVM? Cannot the first one simply "launch" the second one (by invoking its main method or any similar mechanism)? Why is a second process/JVM instance required, since the first app seems to be waiting for the second app's result/end of processing anyway?